# Adding Vue to existing old website, removing the div instead of displaying old html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im trying to wrap my old website with Vue, so all the old jQuery scripts should still run and all the old HTML should display, however for some reason the `el` and everything inside it is being removed.

This is when using the webpacked version of the script, so for example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p>dsadfasfasfasfas</p>
            <p>dfasdsadasdasdas</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Would display nothing within the body tag. But if I import Vue at the top of the website, and put the below code in place of the webpacked version it works fine!

```
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',
    data: {
        test: 'hello world'
    },
    created() {
        console.log('Vue Running');
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Also this is the **app.js** which gets compiled:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// window.EventBus = new Vue();
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',
    data: {
        test: 'hello world'
    },
    created() {
        console.log('Vue Running');
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: [
        './resources/js/vue/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'app.min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public_html/assets/js/vue')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

**Edit 2**

Just removed the `import vue from 'vue'`, and imported it using the normal `script src=...` way and it works. I was under the impression if I import vue and compile then this would include vue in my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default build exported by the NPM package is the runtime-only build. It doesn’t bring the template compiler. So you would either need to import the full build version of vue in your javascript or create a webpack alias (if you are using webpack).

This issue won't occur when you define templates with the render function or Single File Component.

NOTE:

You don't need `babel-loader` if you dont expect to support older browsers and if you dont use latest ES features and you won't need `vue-loader` if you are not using Single File Components.

Also note that you must include the meta tag in your HTML `<meta charset="utf-8">`

This would work -

```js
// webpack
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: ["./app.js"],
  output: { filename: "./app.min.js" },
  resolve: { alias: { vue: "vue/dist/vue.js" } },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: "vue-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

```js
// app.js

import Vue from "vue";

// OR You do this if you dont want to use webpack alias
// import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';

window.app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { message: "Hello Vue!" },
  created() {
    console.log("<><><> Vue Created");
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
<script src="app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay, only just had time to test this and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: It's funny that OP's config doesn't have `babel-loader`, you also said that OP doesn't need it, but your config contains it anyway.

Comment: That's correct @Styx, its because if you are targetting only newer browsers that support ES6+ features then there is no need to transpile your code. You can easily run the example without Babel and it would run anyways. However, it's a good practice to always transpile your code so that you can keep using the latest ES features even though not all browsers may support it right away.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your Webpack config is incomplete.

If you'd open browser console, you'll see there:

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

Your html in `#wrapper` is a template, but Vue can't compile (and use it), because your build includes runtime-only version of Vue.

Simply add this to `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
  },
},
```

That will include runtime+compiler build of Vue.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so,

It's normal because your compiled version looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// window.EventBus = new Vue();
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',
    data: {
        test: 'hello world'
    },
    created() {
        console.log('Vue Running');
    }
});
```

But how the browser know how to import 'vue' ?

Your compiled version is not browser ready,
I think your build configuration is not correct

Can you provide it ?

Comment: Updated my question with the config